# На часах написано "Время безценно , его не вернёш"

Tags: орфография

Вот купил часы , смотрю  на надпись  , и думаю " это ошибки в словах или когда-то давно так писали?"
Помогите решить

Comment: Перед запятыми, а также кавычками, пробелы ставить не следует. Отсутствие точки в конце фразы также считается ошибкой.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, так не писали. В любом случае правильно ***"вернёшь"*** и ***"бесценно"***.

До 1918 г. "безценно" действительно было орфографически правильным написанием, но "вернешь" без мягкого знака в русском языке не было никогда. В украинском такое возможно, но это и не украинский никаким образом.

А какого года часы?!

Comment: На белорусском: "яго не вернеш". Может, какой-то другой славянский?

Comment: @М_Г - нет, это уже фантазии. Нет такого среди славянских.